# Extract entities from Simple passive voice sentence by Python Spacy

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy

Using Python Spacy, how to extract entity from simple passive voice sentence? In the follow sentence, my intention is to extract both "John”  from the sentence as *nsubjpass* and *.ent_*.

sentence =  "John was accused of crimes by David"

Comment: Have you tried `nlp(sentence).ents` ?

Comment: nlp(sentence).ents provides all the entities--sub, object. In this example, it will provide the names of John and David. Here, we are trying to find subject (John)  from a passive voiced sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering to my question because I will ask question on complex sentences later on so that someone can review the answer to the simple sentence and then help me to answer on the complex sentences.

### code

```
each_sentence =  "John was accused of crimes by David"
doc=nlp(each_sentence)

passive_toks=[tok for tok in doc if (tok.dep_ == "nsubjpass") ]
if passive_toks != []:
    print(passive_toks)
```

### Result:

[John]

Answer (score -1):

Go through the spacy 2.0 nightly build. It should have the solution you're looking for.